# Create a line chart in plotly with multiple variables

Tags: python, function, plotly-python

I have a dataset which contains salary of different employee id in different years. The sample data looks like one below:

```
| Id | 2001  | 2002  | 2003  | 2004  | 2005  | 2006  |
|----|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| 1  | 10000 | 10586 | 11646 | 12324 | 15668 | 16447 |
| 2  | 43549 | 45234 | 51233 | 52345 | 53344 | 56544 |
| 3  | 34252 | 35563 | 36433 | 36658 | 37435 | 37799 |
| 4  | 43534 | 45473 | 47574 | 48755 | 49776 | 49876 |
```

I want to create a line chart in python plotly for last 4 years by writing a function so that when new data comes, I don't have to explicitly mention last 4 years. The x axis axis would be the years, y axis would be salary and different line charts would represent the Id.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the years as index, sort by year (just to be sure) and then create a line chart using only the last four rows (years) in the dataframe (`df[-4:]`):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

data= [ { "Id": 1, "2001": 10000, "2002": 10586, "2003": 11646, "2004": 12324, "2005": 15668, "2006": 16447 }, { "Id": 2, "2001": 43549, "2002": 45234, "2003": 51233, "2004": 52345, "2005": 53344, "2006": 56544 }, { "Id": 3, "2001": 34252, "2002": 35563, "2003": 36433, "2004": 36658, "2005": 37435, "2006": 37799 }, { "Id": 4, "2001": 43534, "2002": 45473, "2003": 47574, "2004": 48755, "2005": 49776, "2006": 49876 } ]
df=pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('Id')
df = df.T.sort_index()
df[-4:].plot.line()
```

Or if you wish to wrap it in a function:

```
def get_plot(dataframe):
  return dataframe.T.sort_index()[-4:].plot.line()
```

Result:

[image]